# Python Syntax Errors after print

Tags: python

Everything was working fine in this program I've been writing, and then out of nowhere I started getting all sorts of weird errors. For example:

```
    print Bounds[atomCounter][i][2]
    elif Bounds[atomCounter][i][2] == 'S':
```

Gives the error:

```
elif Bounds[atomCounter][i][2] == 'S':
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It didn't give this error like ten minutes ago, and it doesn't unless the print statement is there. If the print statement isn't there, I get an index out of bounds error - but that shouldn't but the case, because the print statement works (just causes an error in the code after it)... anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: First guess is indentation error since before an `elif` you have to have an `if` and it needs to be indented, which your `print` does not appear to be.  It'd be more helpful if you posted the whole `if`/`elif` block.

Comment: Another thing to check: ensure you don't have `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file.

Comment: do you have an "if" before the print ? :)

Comment: Voting the question +1 as compensation. Can't see why it was downvoted, and the downvoter hasn't left a comment explaining why (he should).

Comment: -1: Too little code to reason out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you're using `elif`, but you can only do that after an if or another elif block. So of course that wouldn't work.

Since it looks like you might have an if block before what you've written, try indenting the print line and see if that works.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought this was a much bigger problem than that - thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @laplacian Accept the answer if it worked, if you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this - I thought I was probably supposed to do something like that, but couldn't find it.